# How can I estimate the size of an Oracle index?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm considering adding an index to an Oracle table, but I'd like to first estimate the size of the index after it has been built (I don't need a precise size - just an estimate.)

Supposing I have access to all of the meta-data about the table (number of rows, columns, column data types, etc) that I can execute any arbitrary Oracle SQL query to get additional data about the current state of the table, and I know what I would want the index definition to be, how can I estimate this size?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can estimate the size of an index by running an `explain plan` on the create index statement:

```
create table t as
  select rownum r 
  from   dual 
  connect by level <= 1000000;

explain plan for
  create index i on t (r);

select * 
from   table(dbms_xplan.display(null, null, 'BASIC +NOTE'));

PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 1744693673                                                                                                                 

---------------------------------------                                                                                                     
| Id  | Operation              | Name |                                                                                                     
---------------------------------------                                                                                                     
|   0 | CREATE INDEX STATEMENT |      |                                                                                                     
|   1 |  INDEX BUILD NON UNIQUE| I    |                                                                                                     
|   2 |   SORT CREATE INDEX    |      |                                                                                                     
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL   | T    |                                                                                                     
---------------------------------------                                                                                                     

Note                                                                                                                                        
-----                                                                                                                                       
   - estimated index size: 4194K bytes
```

Look at the "Note" section at the bottom: **estimated index size: 4194K bytes**

Answer (score 10):

You can use these [Oracle Capacity planning and  Sizing Spreadsheets](http://www.rampant-books.com/download_sizing_spreadsheets.htm).

For something not quite as full-blown, if you just want back of the envelope type [rough estimates for the index](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=575619):

> Calculate the average size of each of
>   the columns that make up the index key
>   and sum the columns plus one rowid and
>   add 2 bytes for the index row header
>   to get the average row size. Now add
>   just a little to the pctfree value for
>   the index to come up with an overhead
>   factor, maybe 1.125 for pctfree of 10.
>
> number of indexed table rows X avg row
>   len X 1.125
>
> Note - if the index contains nullable
>   columns then every table row may not
>   appear in the index. On a single
>   column index where 90% of the columns
>   are null only 10% would go into the
>   index.
>
> Compare estimate to tablespace extent
>   allocation method and adjust final
>   answer if necessary.
>
> Also a larger overhead factor may be
>   better as the index gets bigger since
>   the more data indexed the more branch
>   blocks necessary to support the index
>   structure and the calculation really
>   just figures for leaf blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from version 10gR2 you can use `DBMS_SPACE.CREATE_INDEX_COST`

```
DBMS_SPACE.CREATE_INDEX_COST (
   ddl             IN    VARCHAR2,
   used_bytes      OUT   NUMBER,
   alloc_bytes     OUT   NUMBER,
   plan_table      IN    VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL);
```

From the docs: "This procedure determines the cost of creating an index on an existing table. The input is the DDL statement that will be used to create the index. The procedure will output the storage required to create the index."

See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_space.htm#ARPLS68101

**Example** (also at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9e089/7)):

```
DECLARE 
 ub NUMBER; 
 ab NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
 DBMS_SPACE.CREATE_INDEX_COST (
    ddl             => 'CREATE INDEX x_1 ON t1 (a,b,c) TABLESPACE users',
    used_bytes      => ub,
    alloc_bytes     => ab
   );
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Used MBytes: ' || ROUND(ub/1024/1024)); 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Alloc MBytes: ' || ROUND(ab/1024/1024)); 
END; 
/
```

Output:

```
Used MBytes: 1
Alloc MBytes: 2
```

Comment: Only 8 years after I needed it - but, handy, nonetheless :)

Answer (score 0):

The below SQL query can be used to know the estimated [index size](https://orahow.com/check-index-on-a-table-and-size-in-oracle/) occupied by a table in oracle.

```sql
SELECT (row_size_in_bytes * cnt_of_rows)/1000/1000/1000 index_size_in_GB
FROM
(
  SELECT table_name ,
         (sum (column_length) / 1048576) * 1000000 row_size_in_bytes
  FROM   user_ind_columns
  WHERE  table_name=UPPER('&Enter_Table_Name')
  GROUP  BY table_name
) A,
(SELECT count(1) cnt_of_rows FROM &Enter_Table_Name );
```